# Program that tells to delete a name in an arraylist when that name is on the list more than once

Tags: java

Program that tells to delete a name on an ArrayList when that name is on the list twice. This is the part of the programIi need help on:

```
if (list.contains(nameToFind) && int i = 1; i < THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP)
                System.out.println("Hey, that name is written twice on the list, edit or delete one of them!");
            }
 else {
                System.out.println(" This name is only written once");
```

Comment: Declaring i in a conditional statement isn’t going to work out. Also if you are checking where i == 1, that’s going to ensure that only the 2nd item in the list gets returned. You want i < list.length()

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** and **downvoted** as it clearly shows little research effort nor attempt to solve your question by yourself. It is also quite unclear as you gave no examples and the code doens't clearly address the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a method to **count** the number of times `list` contains `nameToFind`... in Java 8+, you could use a `filter` and count. Like,

```
if (list.stream().filter(s -> s.equals(nameToFind)).count() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Hey, that name is written twice on the list, "
            + "edit or delete one of them!");
}
```

In earlier versions, you can implement that with a method that iterates the `List` and counts the occurrences of a given `String` like

```
static int count(List<String> al, String name) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String s : al) {
        if (s.equals(name)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And then call it like

```
if (count(list, nameToFind) > 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Love `if (list.contains(nameToFind) && int i = 1; i < THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP)` seems simpler to you? I have posted the simplest and cleanest code I could think of. I suppose you could always take up begonias. They're lovely flowers.

Comment: I am sorry this is not what I meant, I just wanted to understand it better to be able to reproduce something similar in the future without having to ask any more questions.

Comment: Is there a way of doing that with the switch statement?

Comment: A way? Yes. A **more** complicated way.